Need help setting role based users for springboot authentication
this is my github https://github.com/carmmmm/antiFraudApplication
my POST is working, but my GET and DELETE requests don't work. i think i am getting confused with the granted authortity, my Role enums, and how to get it all to work? im not sure why i am not getting it authenticated? I would appreciate any help!!
my user class
package antifraud.model;


import antifraud.enums.Role;
import antifraud.enums.UserStatus;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


//Represents a user.
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus status;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean isAccountLocked;

    @ManyToMany
    private final List<RoleUser> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Collection<RoleUser> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }


    public User(String name, String username, String password, Role role, UserStatus status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public User() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public UserStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(UserStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public boolean isAccountLocked() {
        return isAccountLocked;
    }

    public void setAccountLocked(boolean accountNonLocked) {
        isAccountLocked = accountNonLocked;
    }

}


this is my security config class
package antifraud.config;

import antifraud.service.CustomUserDetailsService;
import antifraud.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

import javax.management.relation.Role;


//Configures Spring Security.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

//    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
//        this.restAuthenticationEntryPoint = restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
//    }
//
//    void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
//    }
//
//    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
//    }



    //    @Override
//    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/user").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/auth/user").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/auth/list").hasAnyRole("ADMINISTRATOR", "MERCHANT", "SUPPORT")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/antifraud/transaction").hasRole("MERCHANT")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/auth/access").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/auth/role").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}

//    private final AuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
//
//
//    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
//        this.restAuthenticationEntryPoint = restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
//    }
//
//    @Bean
//    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        return http
//                .httpBasic()
//                .and()
//                .csrf().disable()
//                .exceptionHandling()
//                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
//                .and()
//                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
//                .and()
//                .authorizeRequests()
//                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/user").permitAll()
//                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/auth/list").authenticated()
//                .requestMatchers("/actuator/shutdown").permitAll()
//                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
//                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toH2Console()).permitAll()
//                .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
//                .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                .and()
//                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
//                .and()
//                .build();
//    }
//
//    @Bean
////    @Override
//    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
//        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
//                .username("user")
//                .password("password")
//                .roles("USER")
//                .build();
//
//        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
//    }


my auth controller class
package antifraud.controller;

import antifraud.dtos.UserDTO;
import antifraud.dtos.UserRoleDto;
import antifraud.dtos.UserStatusDto;
import antifraud.enums.Role;
import antifraud.enums.UserStatus;
import antifraud.model.*;
import antifraud.repository.UserRepository;
import antifraud.exceptions.BadRequestException;
import antifraud.exceptions.ConflictException;
import antifraud.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

//Handles user registration, listing, and deletion.
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;




    @PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        if (user.getUsername() == null || user.getPassword() == null|| user.getName() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        if (userRepository.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(user.getUsername()).isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("User already exists");
        }

        // Determine role based on existing users
        Role role = userRepository.count() == 0 ? Role.ADMINISTRATOR : Role.MERCHANT;
        user.setRole(role);

        // Set default locked status
        user.setAccountLocked(role == Role.ADMINISTRATOR ? false : true);

        // Encode the password and save the user
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        // Prepare the response
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO(savedUser.getName(), savedUser.getUsername(), savedUser.getId(), savedUser.getRole());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(userDTO);
    }

    @PutMapping("/role")
    public ResponseEntity<User> changeUserRole(@RequestBody UserRoleDto userRoleDto) throws ConflictException {
        User user = userService.changeUserRole(userRoleDto.getUsername(), userRoleDto.getRole());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @PutMapping("/access")
    public ResponseEntity<StatusResponse> changeUserStatus(@RequestBody UserStatusDto userStatusDto) throws BadRequestException {
        User user = userService.changeUserStatus(userStatusDto.getUsername(), UserStatus.valueOf(userStatusDto.getOperation()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new StatusResponse("User " + user.getUsername() + " " + user.getStatus().name().toLowerCase() + "!"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @GetMapping("/list")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'MERCHANT', 'SUPPORT')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> listUsers(@RequestBody User user) throws ConflictException {
        if (user.getRole() != Role.ADMINISTRATOR || user.getRole() != Role.MERCHANT || user.getRole() != Role.SUPPORT) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
        List<User> userss = userRepository.findAll();
        // Transform users to DTOs if needed
        List<UserDTO> userDTOs = userss.stream()
                .map(users -> new UserDTO(users.getName(), users.getUsername(), users.getId(), users.getRole()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        userss.forEach(users -> System.out.println("Id: " + users.getId() + "User: " + users.getName() + " - " + users.getUsername() + "Role: " + users.getRole()));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDTOs);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user/{username}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUser(@PathVariable String username) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "User not found"));
        userRepository.delete(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("{\"username\": \"" + username + "\", \"status\": \"Deleted successfully!\"}");
    }
}


my custom user details service
package antifraud.service;

import antifraud.model.User;
import antifraud.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


//Loads user details from the database for authentication.
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                getAuthorities(user)
        );

//        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(user.getUsername())
//                .password(user.getPassword())
//                .authorities(String.valueOf(user.getRole()))
//                .build();
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
        return user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}


my user service
package antifraud.service;


import antifraud.exceptions.BadRequestException;
import antifraud.exceptions.ConflictException;
import antifraud.enums.Role;
import antifraud.enums.UserStatus;
import antifraud.model.User;
import antifraud.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.builder()
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .roles(user.getRole().name())
                .disabled(user.getStatus() == UserStatus.LOCKED)
                .build();
    }

    public User registerUser(String name, String username, String password) {
        Role role = userRepository.count() == 0 ? Role.ADMINISTRATOR : Role.MERCHANT;
        UserStatus status = role == Role.ADMINISTRATOR ? UserStatus.ACTIVE : UserStatus.LOCKED;
        User user = new User(name, username, password, role, status);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User changeUserRole(String username, Role newRole) throws ConflictException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        if (user.getRole() == newRole) {
            throw new ConflictException("User already has the role " + newRole);
        }
        user.setRole(newRole);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User changeUserStatus(String username, UserStatus newStatus) throws BadRequestException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        if (user.getRole() == Role.ADMINISTRATOR) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Cannot change status of ADMINISTRATOR");
        }
        user.setStatus(newStatus);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

}

I am using Postman for my requests and only my POST request works.

You need to override the getAuthorities() method of UserDetails interface. One way to do this is to make User class implement UserDetails interface. Example of overriden method:
public class User implements UserDetails {
    // code...
    
    // There is no parameters for this method
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.name()));
    }
}

Then you need to authenticate the user on request for him to be able to access protected endpoint, you can use authentication with JWT tokens to do so by extending OncePerRequestFilter class.
You can check out this YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnZmeczS_DI.
By the way I suggest using Role.ROLE_VALUE.name() instead of hardcoding strings for role names.
